# Get-SPDeletedSite returning nothing in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am running the `Get-SPDeletedSite` PowerShell command in the SharePoint Farm to get the deleted Site IDs which I will use to restore the deleted Site Collection in SharePoint OnPrem but I get nothing back when I run the `Get-SPDeletedSite` command like so:

[image]

I am expecting a list of deleted Site Collections but it just comes back with nothing, no error no list.

Please let me know how best I can get the ID of the deleted site so that I can use that ID to restore the deleted site.

I will be using the `Restore-SPDeletedSite` Powershell command but I just can't get the Site ID of the deleted site in the first place. Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the **Get-SPDeletedSite** command, you need to pass the parameter.

Some examples are below:

**Example 1.**

```
Get-SPDeletedSite "/"
```

**Description**:

This example gets a deleted site collection from the root site.

**Example 2.**

```
Get-SPDeletedSite '/Site/cat*'
```

**Description**:

This example matches a deleted site collection that contains any combination with the string "cat". The asterisk (*) wildcard character requests a match for multiple characters.

**Example 3.**

```
Get-SPDeletedSite -Identity 610857cb-8414-4a89-8bf3-ad3628f6c86c
```

**Description**:

This example gets a specific deleted site collection by using a site ID.

MSDN Reference URL:

[Get-SPDeletedSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spdeletedsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: When I type the Get-SPDeletedSite "/" command, I get an this error: 
Cannot find an SPDeletedSite object with Id or Url: /.

Comment: Check your manage path, then based on that pass parameter

Comment: btw, the 'SPDeletedSite' command retrieves the list of deleted site from the [SiteDeletion] table in the Content Database. I did a quick check, the [SiteDeletion] table has 0 rows. The question is where did my deleted Site Collection go?

Comment: Try to find the site from site recycle bin

Comment: It is a Site Collection, not sub site, I know we could a easily restore a deleted subsite from its site collection. If the deleted site collection is not present in the [SiteDeletion] table in content db, where did the deleted site go, has the gradual site delete timer job anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

The SPDeletedSite has the same retention period as the first stage recycle bin. By default that is 30 days for SharePoint.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4821a2b2-b0b8-4be6-abe4-30e6e17cf18b/sharepoint-2013-how-long-are-site-collections-retained-after-being-deleted?forum=sharepointadmin